# Question about ClipPlanes

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a cut on a surface. The idea is to show half of the surface with low opacity, and the other one with full opacity. Using ClipPlanes I cannot make it to work, since it seem to affect the whole Show command rather than only the Plot3D in which is contained. I assumed that by plotting 2 times the same function, one with ClipPlanes and a second time without will do the trick but I was wrong.

```
Pl=InfinitePlane[{{0, 1, 0},{0,0,1}, {0, 0, 0}}];
Show[Plot3D[-Log[x^2+y^2],{x,-4,4},{y,-4,6},ClipPlanes->Pl,PlotRange->All, ClipPlanesStyle -> Opacity[0.3]],Plot3D[-Log[x^2+y^2],{x,-4,4},{y,-4,6},ClipPlanes->Pl,PlotRange->All,PlotStyle->Opacity[0.4]]]
```

The idea later is to be able to use Manipulate to visualize any cut of a surface by changing the plane. Also, coloring the curve over the surface will be neat.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit**

We can use two `ClipPlanes`.

Here we avoid use `Show` since `Show` will use the options of the first plot to the others,that is why we can not cut the two plots in two different way.

```
normal = {1, 1, 1};
ani = Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[{{ClipPlanes -> Flatten@{normal, t}, 
     ClipPlanesStyle -> Opacity[0.3], 
     Plot3D[-Log[x^2 + y^2], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 6}, PlotRange -> All,
        PlotStyle -> Green, 
       PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"][[1]]}, {ClipPlanes -> 
      Flatten@{-normal, -t}, 
     Plot3D[-Log[x^2 + y^2], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 6}, PlotRange -> All,
        PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3], 
       PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"][[1]]}}, Axes -> True], {t, -3, 
   3}]
```

[image]

**Original**

Use the form `a*x+b*y+c*z+d<=0` where `{a,b,c}` is the normal of plane.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[-Log[x^2 + y^2], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 6}, 
  ClipPlanes -> {{1, 0, 0, t}}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ClipPlanesStyle -> Opacity[0.3], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 
  0, 2}]
```

[image]

Or maybe

```
normal = {1, 1, 1};
ani = Manipulate[
  Show[Plot3D[-Log[x^2 + y^2], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 6}, 
    MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, normal . {x, y, z}], 
    Mesh -> {{t}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
    MeshShading -> {Opacity[.5], Green}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ClipPlanesStyle -> Opacity[0.3], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
   Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Gray, Hyperplane[normal, t]}]], {t, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but a problem with your answer is that if you tilt the plane then does not work. Hyperplane[{1,1, 0}, -t]

Comment: @root  Set the `normal` of plane.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) to specify the separate regions

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot3D[{
    ConditionalExpression[-Log[x^2 + y^2], x >= -t],
    ConditionalExpression[-Log[x^2 + y^2], x < -t]},
   {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 6},
   PlotStyle -> {Automatic,
     Opacity[op, ColorData[97][2]]},
   PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 6}, {-4, 6}},
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"],
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5],
    Hyperplane[{1, 0, 0}, -t]}]],
 {{op, 0.5, opacity}, 0, 1, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{t, 1}, -4, 4, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but a problem with your answer is that if you tilt the plane then does not work. Hyperplane[{1,1, 0}, -t]

Answer (score 4):

If we use `ClipPlanes` as a *directive* in `PlotStyle` (as opposed to using it as an *option*) and have two copies of the input function in the first argument of `Plot3D` we can get the desired result using a single `Plot3D`:

```
clipplanes = {1, 1, 1, -3/2};

Plot3D[{-Log[x^2 + y^2], -Log[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 6}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[ClipPlanes -> clipplanes], 
       Directive[Opacity[0.4, Green], ClipPlanes -> - clipplanes]},
    PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> ClipPlanes -> InputForm @ clipplanes, 
    BoxRatios -> 1, 
    ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

With a helper function to flip the clipping side we can use  `ClipPlanes -> {a,b,c,d}` or `ClipPlanes -> InfinitePlane[...]` to specify clip planes:

```
ClearAll[flipSide]
flipSide[{a_?NumericQ, b_, c_, d_}] := -{a, b, c, d};
flipSide[ip_InfinitePlane] := SubsetMap[Reverse, ip, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}];
```

***Examples:***

```
clipplanes = {1, 1, 1, -3/2};

Show[Plot3D[{-Log[x^2 + y^2], -Log[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 6}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[ClipPlanes -> clipplanes ], 
        Directive[Opacity[0.4, Green], ClipPlanes -> flipSide[clipplanes ]]},
   PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> ClipPlanes -> InputForm @ clipplanes , 
   BoxRatios -> 1, 
   ImageSize -> 500], 
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Opacity[.5, Gray], 
     clipplanes /. {a_, b_, c_, d_?NumericQ} :> Hyperplane[{a, b, c}, -d]}]]
```

[image]

Replace `clipplanes` above with

```
clipplanes2 = InfinitePlane[{{0, 1.5, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}];
```

to get

[image]

```
frames = Table[With[{cp = {1, 1, 1, -w}}, 
    Show[Plot3D[{-Log[x^2 + y^2], -Log[x^2 + y^2]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 6}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Directive[ClipPlanes -> cp], 
         Directive[Opacity[0.4, Green], ClipPlanes -> -cp]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 6}, {-5, 5}}, 
      BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 450], 
     Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Opacity[.5, Gray], 
       Hyperplane[{1, 1, 1}, w]}]]], {w, -10, 6, 1/4}];


Export["clipplanesanimation.gif", frames, AnimationRepetitions -> ∞]
```

[image]