# Color of the volume under the surface

Tags: plotting, regions

Suppose there is the function Exp[-(x^2+y^2)] which covers a certain volume under its surface. That can be easily illustrated by

Plot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}].

How can I split the volume under the surface into two pieces and color them differently?

I'm trying something like

Plot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x + y < 0]]

which leaves just one part of the split volume.

Comment: Are you looking to actually color the volume under the surface (e.g. between surface and the xy-plane), or are you simply trying to color the surface itself in two different colors (one for each region/piece)?

Comment: The first mentioned option: the volume under the surface and xy plane.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262896/question-about-clipplanes/262897#262897

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Show[MapThread[RegionPlot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)] - z > 0 && #1
    , {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 1.2}
    , PlotPoints -> 60
    , MaxRecursion -> 4
    , Mesh -> 3
    , MeshStyle -> #2
    , PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Lighter@#2]
    ] &
  , {{x + y < 0, x + y >= 0}, {Red, Blue}
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
Plot3D[{Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x + y < 0], Filling -> Bottom, 
 FillingStyle -> Green]
```

[image]